# How to extend the limit for reply from telegram bot and what is the limit of reply from telegram bot?[i am using dialogflow integration]

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram-bot, chatbot

I was using dialogflow integration to create bot for telegram.I am getting replies from bot for small queries but i am not getting replies from the bot for larger multi-line answers expected from the bot.

Answer (score 3):

Telegram has a limit when sending message of 4096 chars, are your answers longer than this?

> 400 BAD_REQUEST   MESSAGE_TOO_LONG    Message was too long. Current maximum length is 4096 UTF8 characters

[[See documentation](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage)]