# How to send a large message to api.telegram.org

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm having trouble sending large messages via bot telegrams. During the search for the problem, I threw off all the extra binding and tested it with curl.

In the case of sending a message with text up to about 1500, everything works, I sent it like this:

```
curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot<ТОКЕН>/sendMessage -d chat_id = <ID_CHATA> -d text = "1100ertyikgnfdhgmcndgbtowewerttysadasdsasadsadddssasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsas "asadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsadsasasadsadsasasadsadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasasadsas"
```

In the case of sending a large message, it stops working, in this case I send a text of 2200 characters in size:

```
curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot<ТОКЕН>/sendMessage -d chat_id = <ID_CHATA> -d text = "2200ertyikgnfdhgmcndgbtowewerttysadasdsasadsadddssasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsas asadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasertyikgnfdhgmcndgbtowewerttysadasdsasadsadddssasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasas adsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsadsasasadsadsasasadsadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasadsasasasasasasasasasasasadsasasadsasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsas
```

Using the -vvvvvv switch for curl, I saw the following details: In the first case (when the message is small and sending is triggered) I see:

Expect: 100-continue HTTP / 1.1 100 Continue HTTP / 1.1 200 OK

In the second case (when I send a large message and the sending does not work) I see:

Expect: 100-continue HTTP / 1.1 100 Continue Empty reply from server Connection #0 to host api.telegram.org left intact Closing connection #0

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an error in the second CURL request. the `-d` param requires a string;

```
curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot<ТОКЕН>/sendMessage -d "chat_id=<ID_CHATA>" -d "text='200ertyikgnfdhgmcndgbtowewe'"
```

Also you close the string before the last char, curl doesn't like that;

```
" sasasasasasasasasasasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsasadsas
```

If I edit your second command to use `-d ""`, I can send it as expected. 
Even with a message of 2578 chars works just fine.

Google tels me there is an **4096 UTF8** char limit; [Git](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/165)
Telegram even send an `TOO_LONG` if the `text` param is too long ;) [So](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672791/how-to-extend-the-limit-for-reply-from-telegram-bot-and-what-is-the-limit-of-rep)

Edit based on comment;
Full command for bash;

```
curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:abcdefghijk/sendMessage -d "chat_id=123456" -d "text='Test'"
```

If this does not work for you, please show the error you receive after running the command

Comment: Hello! Based on your answer, I realized that you need to use such a command, right?

curl -vvvv -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789:DFS0xReoSFWSS6hmSS_1SSS/sendMessage -d "chat_id=-1236367" -d "text='2300 characters located here'"


but it still doesn't work

Comment: @AleksandrGrigorian I've posted the full command! Please check! This works on my machine ;) (Try to add full https url)